# memcopy to change position of digits

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main() {
    size_t n = 0;
    scanf("%Iu", & n);
    int * p1 = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * n); //dynamic memory allocation
    int * p2 = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * n); //dynamic memory allocation
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      scanf("%d", & p1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      scanf("%d", & p2[i]); //input number users want
    }
    if ((n % 2) == 0) { //if n is even
      int c = n / 2;
      memcpy(p1 + c, p2, c * (sizeof(int))); //example:input 1234 and 5678
      printf("%d", p1); //          output 1278
    }
    free(p1); //return the memorys
    free(p2); //return the memorys
  } //end
```

aboved is my code. I want to show something under:

input : 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output: 1278

Comment: what did you give as input?`1234`?

Comment: And each input by `scanf` is a digit?

Comment: 4
1
2
3
4

5
6
7
8
1708992
--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.662 seconds with return value 0

Comment: `p1` isn't an integer but a pointer, so `printf("%d",p1);` will at best display the address stored in the pointer. To print the digits you would need `p1[i]`, just as with `scanf`.

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking?

Comment: Got the question wrong.

Comment: the posted code does not compile! it causes the compiler to output lots of warnings, many of whom are critical.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  One of the warnings regarding: `scanf("%Iu", & n);`  there is NO `%Iu`  (capital `i`) input format specifier,  Perhaps you meant; `scanf("%lu", & n);`  (lowercase `ell`

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {`,  'n' has type `size_t` which does not work well when compared to an `int`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Answer (score -1):

You are jumping by c in p1(1234) but not in p2(5678) that is why you are getting first two digits of p2 instead of last two digits i.e. 1256 not 1278
Update memcpy instruction as follows:

> memcpy(p1 + c, p2 + c, c * (sizeof(int)));

and then print p1 as:

`for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
   printf("%d", p[i]);`